Coveo Numeric Facet Range does not display the title
Currently I am using the latest Coveo For Sitecore version. In my search interface, I have a Coveo Numeric Facet Range facet for a computed field. The values are coming fine when I am using Coveo JavaScript Search Framework CDN Version 2.6063. But this version is very old. So, whenever I remove this older version, by default the latest CDN version is coming and the Title value for this facet starts coming null. Although I can see the correct value in the data original value attribute. Not sure, what is going wrong with the latest CDN version.


If you prefer to continue using the legacy JavaScript Search Framework then the leading practice should be to use the Coveo Dynamic Numeric Facet Range  over the Coveo Numeric Facet Range facet. This article details how you can configure your Coveo Dynamic Numeric Facet Range facet.
Alternatively you can explore one of the modern and lightweight approaches for your search interface implementation here.
